# Forecasting Cashflow based on previous Billing

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prediction, forecasting

Detailed historical data for a utilities company:
customer details, bill posted date, amount billed, amount paid, payment date

Question:
Based on how much has been billed before today, how much do we forecast to be paid in the next 15 days , broken down by days (e.g. day 1 = 1.5 mill, day 2 = 4 mill,...., day 15 = 12 mill)

From my perspective we need to take into consideration both how much has been billed and also the speed at which the payments were made historically, i.e. gap between billed and payment date.

Would like to hear your thoughts about how to tackle this question, and potentially what type of statistical/predictive modelling technique to use for this forecasting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please refer to the posting guidelines in the help documentation before you post.  This question might have a place in StackExchange; SO is for specific programming questions.

Comment: Thanks, got it, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

You really only more or less have the bill amount and how long payment took then. Your best bet is probably to attempt regression analysis.

Comment: Given the breadth of the question compared to your answer, I feel this should be a comment.

Comment: Op asked for "thoughts about how to tackle this question, and potentially what type of statistical/predictive modelling technique to use for this forecasting". It's obviously not an ideal question, as it's broad by way of being quite general and asks for opinion, but this IS an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks Michael, really appreciate your answer. I'm also thinking along the lines of Multiple regression analysis.  I'm quite new to forecasting, so wanted to make sure I'm heading in the right direction. If you have any more tips that would be great (since I'm still learning about regression).

Comment: You're welcome to my opinion. Unfortunately though I've studied AI I've never actually implemented any sort of regression analysis, so any advice I can give you is a little limited. But... I'd suggest plotting some of your data, bill size vs payment time is the obvious one, but bill size vs percentage of bill paid is another, and see if you can get anything that looks vaguely linear, which is obviously easier - if you're lucky a relationship will jump out at you.

Comment: It's possible of course the relationships you discover are weak because payment time and percentage is related relatively little to the amount of the bill, but to the character of the customer. I've been assuming your data is anonymised actually, but if you can link it back to the customer then an individual customers propensity to pay well could be analysed and a forecast made based on the individual customers which have due bills next month could be made... It's also possible you won't achieve more this way because it all evens out. Unfortunately I think you'll discover this only by trying.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, I'll start testing out the different plots to see if any relationships pop out. I'll share my findings once I make some sufficient progress. Cheers.